In search for optimal solution for a minimization problem
I am trying to solve the following optimization problem:
$\begin{align}\min_{\mathbf{c}_{k}} \sum_{k=1}^{K}\frac{q_k}{c_k} \\
\text{s.t. } c_k &\geq t_k \quad \forall k \tag1\label1 \\
\sum_{k=1}^{K} c_k &= F \tag2\label2
\end{align}$
$q_{k}, t_k >0$.
The problem is simple but tricky. If constraint \eqref{1} does not exist, the optimal value of $c_k$ for $k=1,2,\dots,K$ will be $
c_{k}^{*}=\frac{F\sqrt{q_k}}{\sum_{n=1}^{K}\sqrt{q_n}}.$
What would be the solution if the two constraints were considered?
For the case without the first constraint, we will have
$\begin{align}\min_{\mathbf{c}_{k}} \sum_{k=1}^{K}\frac{q_k}{c_k} \\
\text{s.t. }
\sum_{k=1}^{K} c_k &= F \tag3\label3
\end{align}$
I changed inequality \eqref{2} to equality \eqref{3} because optimality holds true to equality. Thus, the Lagrange function of the problem can be expressed as
$$
 \mathcal{L}\left(\left\{f_{k}\right\},\nu\right) =
\sum_{k=1}^{K}
{\frac{ q_{k}}{c_{k}}}
+
\nu \left(\sum_{k=1}^{K}c_{k}-F\right)
$$
where $\nu$ is the Lagrange multiplier for constraint \eqref{3}. The partial derivatives are
\begin{align}
    \frac{\partial \mathcal{L}}{\partial c_{k}} &= -\frac{ q_k}{c_{k}^{2}}+\nu = 0 \\
    \frac{\partial \mathcal{L}}{\partial \nu} &= \sum_{k=1}^{K}c_{k}-F = 0
\end{align}
that yields
\begin{align}
    \nu &= \frac{ q_k}{c_{k}^{2}} \tag4\label4\\
\sum_{k=1}^{K}c_{k} &= F \tag5\label5
\end{align}
Solving \eqref{4} yields
$$c_{k} = \sqrt{\frac{ q_k}{\nu}} \tag6\label6$$
Substituting \eqref{6} into \eqref{5} yields
$$\frac{1}{\sqrt \nu} = \frac{F}{\sum_{k=1}^K \sqrt{q_k}}$$
Hence
$$c_k^*=\frac{F \sqrt{ q_k}}{\sum_{k=1}^{K} \sqrt{{ q_k}}}$$

I have no reason to think there is a closed-forum solution. But it is easily formulated as a (convex) Second Order Cone Problem (SOCP), and solved using a readily available SOCP solver. It should be easy and reliable to solve unless K is gagrantuan or the input data is horribly scaled.  If using a tool such as CVX (or CVXPY,), the built-in function inv_pos can be used, which will do the SOCP formulation under the hood. In CVX, the objective function can be written as minimize(q'*inv_pos(c) where q and c are column vectors. Constraints are c >= t and sum(c) == F.
